# Why these two loops return different results?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, for-loop, pairwise

**Problem statement**

> Given an array arr, find element pairs whose sum equal the second
> argument arg and return the sum of their indices.

Disclaimer, I am not asking for the solution of this problem statement, but about the confusion between the following two loops I tried creating, whose functionality is almost exactly similar but consoling different outputs.

1. First Loop

```
function pairwise(arr, arg) {
  const indexOfPair = []
  for ( let i = 0; i < arr.length -1; i++){
    for (let j = i + 1; j < arr.length -1; j++ ){
      let sum = arr[i] + arr[j]
      if ( sum === arg){
        indexOfPair.push(arr.indexOf(arr[i]), arr.indexOf(arr[j]))
        
      }
      else {
        continue
      }
    }
  }

console.log(indexOfPair)
console.log(indexOfPair.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0))
}

pairwise([1,4,2,3,0,5], 7);
```

**Console Output:[1,3] & 4**

2. Second Loop

```
function pairwise(arr, arg) {
  const indexOfPair = []

  for ( let i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0 ; i--){
    for (let j = i -1; j >= 0; j--){
      let sum = arr[i] + arr[j]
      if ( sum === arg){
        indexOfPair.push(arr.indexOf(arr[i]), arr.indexOf(arr[j]))
      }

    }
  }

  console.log(indexOfPair)
  console.log(indexOfPair.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0))


}

pairwise([1,4,2,3,0,5], 7);
```

**Console output: [5,2,3,1] & 11** -> This is the expected output and I am not getting why these two loops are returning different outcomes.

Comment: Why use indexOf() when you already have the index values as `i` & `j`? Note that if there are duplicate values in the array that indexOf() will only return first one found

Comment: I did not realize that, Does it not make any difference? I was trying to be, precise. Thanks for your input. I will do the necessary edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not getting to the last entry in arr.

```
  for ( let i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++){
    for (let j = i + 1; j < arr.length - 1; j++ )
```

should be

```
  for ( let i = 0; i <= arr.length - 1; i++){
    for (let j = i + 1; j <= arr.length - 1; j++ )
```

Comment: Thanks ! @G-Paz, I did not realize I was doing this simple thing wrong. appreciate it.